# touchBegan in a TableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I use touchesBegan:withEvent: to get the touches of the user in the screen but when i touch a cell in a tableView this method didn't get the tag that i give the view.and the x and y are from the cell and not from the all screen.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{

    UITouch *touch = [[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
    CGPoint finger = [touch locationInView:self];
    int x = finger.x;
    int y = finger.y;

}
```

This is the `touchesBegan:withEvent:` method. there is any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this method :

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

It is a delegate method, so don't forget to connect your delegate and datasource in Interface Builder .

[Apple Documentation - UITableViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDelegate)

Comment: I Want to get the x and the y that was touched in the screen and i can get them when i used this method

Comment: Ok... so you need to use convertPoint method , e.g. :[self convertPoint: finger toView:[UIScreen mainScreen]];

Comment: i can't use because it return uiscreen and not UIView :  [UIScreen mainScreen]

Comment: Yes, sorry it should be : [self convertPoint: finger toWindow:nil]; According the doc, nil is by default the screen.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html